# ajax call in IE is extremely slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following Ajax code in my web page.  It basically makes an Ajax call to the database and returns a bunch of records. 
This code runs fast / well in Firefox but very slow in IE. 
I'm just wondering if there are any ways to optimize this code for IE.

**Code**

```
var fill_test_table = function(data){
        var tr;
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tr=$('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + widget[i].name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + widget[i].age + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + widget[i].status + "</td>");
                tr.append("<a href='widget.html?id=" + widget[i].id + "&age=" + widget[i].age + "&status=" + widget[i].status + "&name=" + widget[i].name.replace("'","%27") + "'</a><button>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>");    
                $("#widget_table").append(tr);
        }
        $("#widget_table").append("</tbody>");
};


$(document).ready ( function() {
               $.ajax({
                url: "/cgi-bin/getwdigets",
                dataType: "json",                
                success: function(data) {
                        fill_test_table(data); 
                      }
                  });
        })
```

I found the following post [jQuery Ajax call very slow in IE, but instant in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715882/jquery-ajax-call-very-slow-in-ie-but-instant-in-firefox) and have tried to implement some of the suggestions made.  But if there are any obvious items that should be fixed, I'd like to know.

Comment: You can use one `.append()`, which will add whole HTML, instead of tons of `.append()`s. That should speed things up.

Comment: Highly doubt it is the Ajax call, it is your loop that is slow.  Do not append on every row! Build up all the rows/cells in a string and append once.

Comment: Also `$("#widget_table").append("</tbody>");` makes no sense

Comment: Use native javascript instead of jQuery when dealing with performance issues.

Comment: @A1rPun I doubt there is big perfomance difference between `$("#widget_table").html(html);` and `document.getElementById('widget_table').innerHTML = html;`

Comment: The main takeaway is this: Only use `.innerHTML` or `$(...).html()` a single time when you intend to change the **entire** content of an element. It can still sort of make sense to add elements in a loop if you're only setting *those element's* HTML.

Comment: @Regent About twice as fast [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-innerhtml-the-better-way/13).

Comment: @A1rPun yes, twice, but what about difference in milliseconds between one `.html()` and one `.innerHTML`? 1 millisecond or less? I do talk only about this particular question.

Comment: @Regent He is doing 5 append's per loop.. I know It's better to use 1 outside of the loop. The statement what I was trying to make is, jQuery is easier to write, but slower in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet it's not the request itself that is slow, but your loop adding the dom elements. Also, you missed the opening `<td>` for the last cell containing the link. This should be quicker:

```
var markup = '';
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    markup += "<tr>"
    + "<td>" + widget[i].name + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + widget[i].age + "</td>"
    + "<td>" + widget[i].status + "</td>"
    + "<td><a href=\"widget.html?id=" + widget[i].id + "&age=" + widget[i].age + "&status=" + widget[i].status + "&name=" + widget[i].name.replace("'","%27") + "\"</a><button>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>"
    + "</tr>";
}
$("#widget_table").append(markup);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is rendering the page, not the ajax call. So you should try somethign like that:

```
var restuls= [];
for (var i= 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
      restuls += "<td>" + widget[i].name + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + widget[i].age + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + widget[i].status + "</td>" +
                       "<a href='widget.html?id=" + widget[i].id + "&age=" + widget[i].age + "&status=" + widget[i].status + "&name=" + widget[i].name.replace("'","%27") + "'</a><button>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td>"                       
}

$('#widget_table').empty().append(restuls);
```

hope it's helps.

Comment: @dot Also you should use `append` as I put in my answer, because `html()` is used when you have to replace the html code, and I think you don't want replace the html.

Comment: Why are you creating an array first, then joingin it? It shouldn't be that much overhead, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the ajax call. The for loop is the reason that its very slow in IE.

Try to create a string and then append it to the DOM.

Or

Try creating document fragment and then append the fragment in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var fill_test_table = function(data){
    var innerHtml = '';
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        innerHtml +='<tr><td>' + widget[i].name + '</td>'
            +'<td>' + widget[i].age + '</td>'
            +'<td>' + widget[i].status + '</td>'
            +'<td><a href="widget.html?id=' + widget[i].id + '&age=' + widget[i].age + '&status=' + widget[i].status + '&name=' + widget[i].name.replace("'","%27") + '"</a><button>Edit</button>&nbsp;</td></tr>';    
    }
    $("#widget_table").html('<tbody>'+innerHtml+'</tbody>');
};
```

Comment: I hope to see better explanation of your idea than _try this_

Comment: you can tell the difference just by seeing.. there is no `$ create 'tr'` and no `append()`s. it builds the `innerHtml` as plain sting and appends as `html` to table.